# Why wouldn't a specific environment override environment.rb in rails here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, app-config

I'm trying to work on a Rails site here in it's development environment, where I want to test email delivery, and I can't work out why properties declared in the main `environment.rb` aren't being overwritten by the more specific `development.rb` file that I presume would be loaded when booting a rails app.

My understanding here is that values in more specific environment config files like this should override the shared 'environment.rb' config file, so if I have declared some email settings like so in `config/environment.rb`...

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.hostingcompany.com',
  :port           => 25,
  :domain         => 'productiondomain.net',
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name      => "productiondomainmailer",
  :password       => "TOP_SEKRIT"
}
```

... then code here in `config/environments/development.rb` below should override the `ActionMailer:Base.smtp_settings` hash:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :domain         => 'developmentdomain.net'
}
```

However, when load the app in the development environment, or from `script/console` to check the value of `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings[:domain]`, it's still listed as 'productiondomain.net'.

Why might this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the configuration for your development environment put:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =
```

rather than:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings =
```

in **config/environments/development.rb**

Note that in **config/environments/development.rb** you will need to specify the full set of settings and not just `:domain` as the hash overwrites the existing value rather than being merged with it.

And similarly, set the default in **config/environments.rb** by putting `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings =` inside the `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|` block.

Comment: This seems to have resolved it, thanks Mikej!

I'm assuming changing settings inside the initializer loop, using `config.action_mailer.relevant_setting` is the preferred way to make these changes now over `ActionMailer::Base.relevant_setting` now. Why does changing it through the config block work, but not through the ActionMailer::Base class not work?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is due to the execution order. If you put ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = .. at the end of config/environments.rb, outside the Initializer.run block then this will run *after* the contents of config/environments/development.rb
so will overwrite your development specific settings. If you try to reference ActionMailer::Base inside the block passed to Initializer.run this this will fail as the block is yielded to *before* the ActionMailer framework has been loaded by Initializer.process. Hence the use of config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = ..

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.some_host.com',
  :port           => 25,
  :domain         => 'developmentdomain.net',
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name      => 'blabla',
  :password       => "some_pass"  
}
```